# Convergence of series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}(a_k+2a_{k+1}+a_{k+2})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let's consider the two series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}d_k$, where $d_k=\frac{1}{4}(a_k+2a_{k+1}+a_{k+2})$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$.

I could already show that the following statement is true:

"If $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ is convergent $\implies \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}d_k$ is convergent".

However, I have failed to prove the converse: "if $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}d_k$ is convergent $\implies \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ is also convergent". Maybe, the converse doesn't hold at all? So far I haven't found any counter example.

Comment: If $a_k=(-1)^k$ then $d_k=0$ for all $k$